# I am using node version 14.18.1 and this is the error I am facing : opts.node.rangeBy is not a function with postcss : ^9.0.0

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postcss

Stack:
TypeError: opts.node.rangeBy is not a function

IN THIS FILE:

```
    if (opts.node && opts.node.source) {
          let range = opts.node.rangeBy(opts)
          this.line = range.start.line
          this.column = range.start.column
          this.endLine = range.end.line
          this.endColumn = range.end.column
        }
```

and these are the dependencies:

```
      "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
        "gulp-livereload": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.0.9",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.0.0",
        "postcss-header": "^2.0.0",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-prefixer": "^2.1.2",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
        "postcss-scss": "^3.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.11"
      },
```

I tried changing the postcss version, but still facing the same issue.